# Having trouble promisifying obscure library and then using it in a coroutine

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

So I'm trying to promisify the splunk-sdk library, but It seems like I don't understand how promisifying works, at least with coroutines.

NOTE: I'm using bluebirdjs

Here's the process I've been trying to recreate in a coroutine:

```
// Search everything and return the first 100 results
var searchQuery = "search * | head 100";

// Set the search parameters
var searchParams = {
  exec_mode: "blocking",
  earliest_time: "2012-06-20T16:27:43.000-07:00"
};

// A blocking search returns the job's SID when the search is done
console.log("Wait for the search to finish...");

// Run a blocking search and get back a job
service.search(
  searchQuery,
  searchParams,
  function(err, job) {
    console.log("...done!\n");

    // Get the job from the server to display more info
    job.fetch(function(err){
      // Display properties of the job
      console.log("Search job properties\n---------------------");
      console.log("Search job ID:         " + job.sid);
      console.log("The number of events:  " + job.properties().eventCount); 
      console.log("The number of results: " + job.properties().resultCount);
      console.log("Search duration:       " + job.properties().runDuration + " seconds");
      console.log("This job expires in:   " + job.properties().ttl + " seconds");

      // Get the results and display them
      job.results({}, function(err, results) {
        var fields = results.fields;
        var rows = results.rows;
        for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
          var values = rows[i];
          console.log("Row " + i + ": ");
          for(var j = 0; j < values.length; j++) {
            var field = fields[j];
            var value = values[j];
            console.log("  " + field + ": " + value);
          }
        }
      })

    });

  }
);
```

Its from [this](http://dev.splunk.com/view/javascript-sdk/SP-CAAAEFA) tutorial

This is what my efforts have yielded (Pun partially intended?)

```
    "use strict";
//Get the splunk sdk
var splunkjs = require('splunk-sdk');
//get promise dependencies
Promise = require("bluebird");
//get request dependencies
var request = require('request-promise');

//Promisify dependencies
splunkjs = Promise.promisifyAll(splunkjs);


//create a promise generator
exports.splunkTest = Promise.coroutine(function*(){
      try{
        // Create a Service instance and log in
        let service = yield Promise.promisifyAll(Promise.resolve(new splunkjs.Service({
          username:"user",
          password:"password",
          scheme:"https",
          host:"host",
          port:"8089",
          version:"6.3.2"
        })));
        // Pass the search query
        let searchQuery = "search * | head 100";
        let searchParams = {
          exec_mode: "blocking"
        };
        let job = yield Promise.resolve(service.search(searchQuery,searchParams,function(err,job){return console.log("running");return job;}));
        //JOB DOESN'T CONTAIN FUNCTIONS!!! :(
        return yield Promise.resolve(job);
      } catch (e){
        console.log(e)
      }

    });
```

The job object doesn't have any function in my, probably erroneous, attempt at converting the process into a coroutine.

Can somebody offer some general guidance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `splunkjs.Service` constructor won't be returning a promise, so you don't have to `yield` it. You do want to run `promisifyAll` on it, to promisify all its methods.

So:

```
let service = Promise.promisifyAll(new splunkjs.Service({...}));
```

Next, you want to call the promisified version of `search`, which will be called `searchAsync`. Since that will return a promise, you'll yield it (and you don't pass a callback);

```
let job = yield service.searchAsync(...);
```

Lastly, you just return what you want to return:

```
return job;
```